# get_attachment_link() adds a hashtag to URL

Tags: permalinks, attachments

I'm using the get_attachment_link() function in a site I'm developing and it's returning a really weird result. For some reason it adds #main at the end of every url.

http://domain.com/post_title/attachment_title/#main

Am I the only one getting this strange result? Any ideas?

Comment: Output from this function depends upon your permalink setting read this [get_attachment_link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_attachment_link#Return_value)

Comment: According to that page, the function in my site should return: http://wp.example.net/path_to_post/post_name/attachment_name. In my case, it's returning http://wp.example.net/path_to_post/post_name/attachment_name/#main instead

Comment: switch to default theme, disable plugins, check if issue persists. you have some custom code somewhere modifying it, WordPress on its own does not add this.

Comment: You are right! underscores, the starter theme I'm using, was filtering the attachment_link filter.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments above, the problem is with the _s theme. The specific function causing the problem is [`_s_enhanced_image_navigation()` in `inc/extras.php`](https://github.com/Automattic/_s/blob/master/inc/extras.php#L35). The problem can be resolved by changing the first `if` statement in the function to this:

```
if ( is_admin() || ( ! is_attachment() && ! wp_attachment_is_image( $id ) ) )
    return $url;
```